# Hadoop nodemanager not starting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, nodemanager

I am setting up a single node cluster. I am following the https://dev.to/awwsmm/installing-and-running-hadoop-and-spark-on-ubuntu-18-393h tutorial. However, My nodemanager is not starting.

```
14468 SecondaryNameNode
14648 ResourceManager
14074 NameNode
15293 Jps
14223 DataNode
```

Below are the node manager logs:

```
2020-08-07 14:13:52,796 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Failed to initialize mapreduce_shuffle 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The ServiceName: mapreduce_shuffle  set in yarn.nodemanager.aux-services is invalid.The valid service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with numbers
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:527)
2020-08-07 14:13:52,800 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The ServiceName: mapreduce_shuffle  set in yarn.nodemanager.aux-services is invalid.The valid service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with numbers
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The ServiceName: mapreduce_shuffle  set in yarn.nodemanager.aux-services is invalid.The valid service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with numbers
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:527)
2020-08-07 14:13:52,801 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The ServiceName: mapreduce_shuffle  set in yarn.nodemanager.aux-services is invalid.The valid service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with numbers
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The ServiceName: mapreduce_shuffle  set in yarn.nodemanager.aux-services is invalid.The valid service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with numbers
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:527)
2020-08-07 14:13:52,802 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The ServiceName: mapreduce_shuffle  set in yarn.nodemanager.aux-services is invalid.The valid service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with numbers
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The ServiceName: mapreduce_shuffle  set in yarn.nodemanager.aux-services is invalid.The valid service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with numbers
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at 

2020-08-07 14:13:52,816 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at es/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Here is my yarn-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>  
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I have saw many posts where `mapreduce.shuffle` has to be changed to `mapreduce_shuffle`. However, in my yarn-site.xml I already have `mapreduce_shuffle`.

Comment: Hadoop version??

Answer (score 2):

1. from the logs `mapreduce_shuffle`  , I could see two spaces are appending after the `mapreduce_shuffle` value. could you correctly type and copy into yarn-site.xml instead of directly copying it from blogs. this may due to some special characters appeneded in `mapreduce_shuffle` string
2. replace `yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class` with `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class` tag and start the hadoop it should work.

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>  
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: by further analyse logs I found that my service mapreduce_shuffle was already running hence not able to initialize this service again . To resolve this. I restart the system and installed hadoop again

Comment: oh, that's strange!. anyway glad to know your issue got fixed!